# How to parse a complex ksoap Object to String on Android?

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2, ksoap

I am using KSOAP2 (3.0.0) getting a response like the following:

```
    <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
        <env:Header>
        </env:Header>
        <env:Body>
            <ns2:ExampleResponse xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/" >
                <result>
                    <answer>0</answer>
                    <message>
                        <last>0</last>
                    </message>
                </result>
            </ns2:ExampleResponse>
        </env:Body>
    </env:Envelope>
```

I want to capture "last, I used the following:

```
String ans1 = response.getPropertyAsString("answer"); // 0
String ans2 = response.getPropertyAsString("message"); // anyType{last=0; }
String ans3 = response.getPropertyAsString("last"); // illegal property: last
```

As shown is just working "answer".
How can I get "last"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try following:

```
// Fetches message as soap object, rather than just its string representation
SoapObject messageObject = (SoapObject) response.getProperty("message");

// Fetches last from above oject
String lastAsString = messageObject.getPropertyAsString("last");
```

Hope it helps!